# PhoneGap not running Angular JS code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, phonegap-build, phonegap

I just started learning angularJS using phonegap and I have a simple HTML code and a few lines of angularjs code. Everything works fine in the browser but only the HTML code works in the phonegap when I try to run it on my Android phone. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\learning\learn\angular-1.5.8"></script>

    <script src="C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\learning\learn\www\me.js"></script>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
         <div ng-app="app3" ng-controller="ctrl1">
      <span>Values:</span>


      <input type="text" ng-model="first" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="second" />

      <h1>hello there buddy</h1>
      <button ng-click="update()">Sum</button>
      <br><br>


      {{calculation}}
     </div>

 <script>
        var app = angular.module('app3', []);

    app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {

    $scope.first = 1;
    $scope.second = 2; 

    $scope.update = function(){

        $scope.calculation = (+$scope.first + +$scope.second);
    };
    });
    <!-- Load the AngularJS library -->
    </script>

    <!-- Load the JS Module -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
    var app = angular.module('app3', []);

    app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {

$scope.first = 1;
$scope.second = 2; 

$scope.update = function(){

    $scope.calculation = (+$scope.first + +$scope.second);
};
});
```

Comment: for some reason its not showing the first few lines, it has this as well:

<script src="C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\learning\learn\angular-1.5.8"></script>

Comment: I think your phone is not able to access your workstation harddisk -> `C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\learning\learn\www\me.js` & `C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\learning\learn\angular-1.5.8` ;-)

Comment: i see, ok do you know how can i fix that issue?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path for cordova (like "./") instead of absolute path (
), that's way the script can't be loaded. Anyway you can debug your solution in android using chrome and attaching device or iOS using safari inspector.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href=".">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a basic example. src should match with the correct path for this file.